# How to update array elements in mongodb

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I have data in mongoDB like below

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("57c40e405e62b1f02c445ccc"),
  "sharedPersonId": ObjectId("570dec75cf30bf4c09679deb"),
  "notificationDetails": [
     {
       "userId": "57443657ee5b5ccc30c4e6f8",
       "userName": "Kevin",
       "isRed": true 
     } 
   ] 
}
```

Now i want to update `isRed` value as `false` How to write query for this. I have tried something like below

```
var updateIsRedField = function(db, callback) {
    db.collection('notifications').update({_id:notificationId},
    {
        $set: { "notificationDetails.$": {isRed: false}},
    }, function(err, results) {
        callback();
    });
};

MongoClient.connect(config.database, function(err, db) {
    assert.equal(null, err);
    updateIsRedField(db, function() {
        db.close();
    });
    return res.json({});
});
```

Comment: You got any error while updating? Or is not it updated?

Comment: It is not updated.

Comment: Can you check the output for  `db.collection('notifications').find({_id:notificationId})`? Is it giving any record or not?

Comment: I am getting result because last time it updates entire `notificationDetails` array as `isRed : false`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the positional **[`$`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/)** operator acts as a placeholder for the first element that matches the query document, and the array field must appear as part of the query document hence the query `{ "notificationDetails.isRed": true }` is essential to get the **[`$`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/)** operator to work properly:

```
db.collection('notifications').update(
    { "_id": notificationId, "notificationDetails.isRed": true },
    { "$set": { "notificationDetails.$.isRed": false } },
    function(err, results) {
        callback();
    }
);
```